# Why is tcpdump so much faster than python implementation?

Tags: python, tcpdump

First of all, English is not my native language, i hope i can write down my problem, that everyone understands it.

I'm working currently with the CAN Protocol, i have much messages that i need to processing (~ 500 kB/s).
But no matter what library i'm using, my code uses a lot of CPU usage. While tcpdump needs only 1%..

I tried it with the python-can library, also with native socket implementation and now with the pcap python library.
With every library it's the same thing, it needs a lot of CPU usage.

My current implementation needs ~13%, and tcpdump 1% with writing to file.

Has anybody an idea, how tcpdump can be so extremly efficient? Have anyone similar problems?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Python is a higher level language that runs C code in the back (usually). A program written directly in C or other lower level languages would always be faster and more efficient.